# securing remote CFCs in Coldfusion

Tags: ajax, web-services, security, coldfusion

I'm having a lot of trouble finding information about securing remote functions on Coldfusion CFCs for AJAX calls.  Lets say you're retrieving sensitive information for a user after the user logs in to the site via an AJAX call.  You call something like this:

https://www.mySite.com/pathToCFC/MyCFC.cfc?method=getBankInfo&userID=2343

So this is obviously super insecure as anyone could call this from a browser and change userID to get different user's bank info.

I've read about using the roles attribute on the remote function and using cflogin to authenticate a user, but even with this in place, wouldn't you have to pass the userID like the above call?  Wouldn't an authenticated user still be able to switch the userID to discover new user's bank info?

Comment: I think you would need to clarify. If they are two applications talking, then generally they would end up with a shared public key system and you have a handshake. If you are talking about exposing a webservice for the public to use for a fee, for instance, then they typically just send a 128 bit unique id (UUID) that is tied to an account in the web service database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't pass the userid from the client.  The userid and other sensitive data should be stored server-side.  In fact, every bit of data passed from the client must be considered suspect, and validated.

So, if you're using cflogin, for instance, and you're on a single server, or a sticky-sessioned server, then store the userid and any other critical information in the session scope.

On each request, you fetch this data from the session, not from what the client provides.

This a good starting point on [User Security in Coldfusion](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appSecurity_04.html)

Comment: so if I called the cfc via an ajax call, would the remote cfc be able to access the session scope?  If the call from the browser passes no arguments to the remote function, how does this cfc know what session it needs to use?

Comment: When you turn on session management in the application.cfc (or application.cfm), the CF server uses session cookies (cfid and cftoken).  So, on each request, the cfserver examines those cookies, and if they're valid, allows access to the session variables for that session.

Comment: lets say I create a remote CFC function on one website on a given server, and create a different website using the same CFserver.  This website allows session management and then makes a call to this remote CFC that resides in the folders of another website.  The browser calls this function on the clientside.  Would the remote CFC still know to use the session scope for this particular application?  Does a session cookie get somehow passed automatically to these remote functions when they are called on the client side?

Comment: It depends.  The session scope belongs to an application.  "Applications" in Coldfusion are somewhat amorphous.  The only thing that distinguishes one application from another on a single Coldfusion server is the application name, set either in the application.cfc or the application.cfm.  So, if the two websites had different application names, then they would not share sessions.  If the two websites had the same application name, then they would.

Comment: Paying attention to what edward said, you would never send a userid as you have above in any situation. Either use a UUID as the key or set a UUID in addition to the userID that you are using. You can pass the UUID through https without having the ability to change characters to access another account as you noted above.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second, if you have user X which has to request his details from the server, you don't need his ID, you have it in session, or if you use cflogin feature you'll have getUserAuth().

I you have administrator who can see other users details and you're worried about him seeing bank details you need roles, cf's roles or your custom solution etc.

In any case you don't need to send explicit call "gimme bank account details for user 3456"..